# Traverse graph and return class instances created by recursively calling node with children for arguments

Tags: python, recursion, directed-acyclic-graphs

Have a graph mapping class types to a list of their arguments. How do I return the roots instantiated with their ancestors for arguments? (Apologies for what is probably a terrible description of my problem). Consider the following:

```
graph = {Foo: [42], Baz: [None], Bar: [Baz], FooBar: [Foo, Bar], Qux: [True]}
```

For roots returned by `set(graph).difference(chain.from_iterable(graph.values()))`, I expect two values, `qux` and `foobar`, created like the following:

```
qux = Qux(True)
foobar = FooBar(Foo(42), Bar(Baz(None)))
```

Here is additional code to reproduce the example:

```
from itertools import chain


class Node:
    name = None
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args


class FooBar(Node):
    name = 'foobar'


class Foo(Node):
    name = 'foo'
    parent = FooBar


class Bar(Node):
    name = 'bar'
    parent = FooBar


class Baz(Node):
    name = 'baz'
    parent = Bar


class Qux(Node):
    name = 'qux'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to create a different class for each instance? That's not what classes are for!

Comment: That is the case in this simplified example.

Comment: I suggest modifying your code to create a different object *of the same class* for each instance. Don't create a different class for every node of your graph.

Comment: Thank you, though in the actual application what these classes mock are used/reused extensively. Again, this is a simplified example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this recursive function:

```
def get_inst (graph, arg):
    val = graph[arg]
    
    return arg(*(el if type(el) != type else get_inst (graph, el) for el in val))
```

**Sample usage of this function:**

```
roots = set(graph).difference(chain.from_iterable(graph.values()))

for root in roots:
    val = get_inst(graph, root)
```

Comment: Great solution. Thank you.